# Django + Nginx configuration (getting "Welcome to nginx!")

Tags: django, nginx

I have Django + Nginx + Gunicorn on Ubuntu. Certificates generated with Letsencrypt.

In */etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject* I have:

```
server {
    server_name myproject.com www.myproject.com;
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://myproject.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name myproject.com www.myproject.com;

    listen 443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myproject.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myproject.com/privkey.pem;

    client_max_body_size 1G;

    root /home/myname/myproject;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass https://unix:/home/myname/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

In */etc/nginx/sites-available/default*, except commented lines, I have:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

In */etc/nginx/sites-enabled* I have default and myproject.

When I go to https://myproject.com, I see "Welcome to nginx!", but I expect to see Django's default page.
What am I doing wrong that it redirects to "Welcome to nginx!"?

Comment: What site are you expecting to see?

Comment: Whenever nginx is configured it always show its welcome page. What side do you want to see? For detailed step-by-step tutorial to successfully deploy django app with gunicorn + nginx you check this link- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: I expect to see Django's default page. I followed that tutorial and it worked fine with http, but after using lets encrypt for some reason it started to redirect to nginx default page.

Answer (score 6):

Just disable default config:

```
rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
systemctl reload nginx
```

Comment: Thxs! Disabled default. After that I got 502 error. When changed  proxy_pass from https to http, it worked fine.