# "Nginx welcome to nginx" displays www. prefix; works fine without

Tags: nginx

I set up Lets encrypt using Certbot; everything works fine when I view my website via “website.com”, however when I use “www.website.com” I get a welcome to nginx landing page.

I’ve attempted to fix this by following a similar question posted on the community:[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54244753/django-nginx-configuration-getting-welcome-to-nginx], following the step outline in the post I delete the default using rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default but each time I try my website thereafter with the 'www' prefix it redirect to https://www.website.com with the error: This site can’t be reached ...unexpectedly closed the connection".

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default:**

```
server {
         listen 80 default_server;
         listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #       deny all;
    #}
}

# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/website:**

```
server {
    server_name website.com www.website.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/…/website;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/website.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = www.website.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = website.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name server_name website.com www.website.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove one of the server_name s.

[image]

Remember to `nginx -s reload`. The rest of your code seams fine.

Did you use `certbot --nginx` to get ssl for `example.com` or `www.example.com`?
Because I see both of them here.

[image]

If you still have the same issue, I suggest you remove the file, and also the shortcut, and start over. Once you make sure both `example.com` or `www.example.com` work correctly, then go after issuing the ssl.
And remember, you just need to get ssl for either `example.com` or `www.example.com`.

Comment: Thanks @Parsa Arvaneh for the reply. I tried the fix but got the error: "This page isn’t working www.website.com didn’t send any data",

Comment: A big thank you @Parsa Arvaneh; your reply was most helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help.